# LINQ IEnumerable<T[]> to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

If a query returns IEnumerable, how can I make it flat and have all the T from the arrays in a single IEnumerable?

```
var types = from genericType in subscriber.GetType().GetInterfaces()
            where genericType.IsGenericType 
            && genericType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (ISubscriber<>)
            select genericType.GetGenericArguments();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` method from `Linq`:

```
var flat = types.SelectMany(x => x);
```